# I am using Ubuntu 13.10 and i can not access some website. my internet is wired (DSL)

Tags: networking

I have some problem for quite some time in Ubuntu connecting to particular sites like:

http://www.thedailystar.net/

http://www.ixwebhosting.com/

I have tried various browsers, like Firefox, Chrome, Midori... none of them can load those websites. I am including my `ifconfig` and `ping` of the site. It will be great help if someone can give me the solution to the problem.

```
rashed@rashed-HP-430-Notebook-PC:~$ ifconfig

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:9c:02:93:f2:85  
          inet6 addr: fe80::29c:2ff:fe93:f285/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:142049 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:82404 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:97855440 (97.8 MB)  TX bytes:10101995 (10.1 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:8997 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8997 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:829610 (829.6 KB)  TX bytes:829610 (829.6 KB)

ppp0      Link encap:Point-to-Point Protocol  
          inet addr:10.70.60.26  P-t-P:10.70.70.1  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1492  Metric:1
          RX packets:10826 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:11408 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:3 
          RX bytes:6995506 (6.9 MB)  TX bytes:2105743 (2.1 MB)

rashed@rashed-HP-430-Notebook-PC:~$ ping www.thedailystar.net
PING iu72u.x.incapdns.net (199.83.133.234) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 199.83.133.234.ip.incapdns.net (199.83.133.234): icmp_req=1 ttl=52 time=325 ms
64 bytes from 199.83.133.234.ip.incapdns.net (199.83.133.234): icmp_req=2 ttl=52 time=325 ms
64 bytes from 199.83.133.234.ip.incapdns.net (199.83.133.234): icmp_req=3 ttl=52 time=312 ms
rashed@rashed-HP-430-Notebook-PC:~$ ping www.ixwebhosting.com
PING www.ixwebhosting.com (98.130.254.120) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from www.ixwebhosting.com (98.130.254.120): icmp_req=1 ttl=47 time=340 ms
64 bytes from www.ixwebhosting.com (98.130.254.120): icmp_req=2 ttl=47 time=341 ms
64 bytes from www.ixwebhosting.com (98.130.254.120): icmp_req=3 ttl=47 time=342 ms
```

Comment: Neither of those websites are actually online. See [here](http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/).

Comment: oh here they're running fine.. tried in [IsItDownRightNow.com](http://www.isitdownrightnow.com) ..they're UP and reachable.

Comment: maybe you'd want to try a proxy server to visit those sites..

Comment: thank you, tor browser actually fixed the problem, i had.

Comment: Does your country filter the internet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ixwebhosting.com** returned the same IP.

**dailystar.net** for me was 149.126.77.234, which differs from yours.

You could be sensored to certain websites by your ISP, or by your country.
Try accessing the above sites through one of the web proxy sites below.

[webproxy.net](http://www.webproxy.net)

[hidemyass.com](http://www.hidemyass.com/proxy/)

If you can get to the websites that way, you can google for a good proxy server. Then go to network settings in your ubuntu and manually add the proxy IP and Port.

With this setting, all of your browsers will go through the proxy.

Otherwise, you can do what I do.  Just set the proxy in Firefox, then use Chromium for non proxy connection.

#### Useful link:

- [How to Configure Ubuntu desktop to use your proxy server](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-configure-ubuntu-desktop-to-use-your-proxy-server.html)

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I am using tor browser, it actually fixed the problem, i had previously. if you have any better solution then tor browser, pleas share it. i am new user of ubuntu, any kind of suggestion will be appreciated.